# Disable default behavior of options popup in a text input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you click on or type in an input field it shows you the suggestions from options in the datalist.
I have overridden the input on click event so it clears the input field to make it easier to start typing again once you select the input element.
This produces an undesired effect of having the list of options pop up only listing the previous option (or the option that match the previous input). I would like it to list all the options.
[image: Results on clicking on input field]

I have also overridden the backspace behavior to clear the field as well and I prevent the unwanted behavior by preventing default key function (e.preventDefault();)

```
$('element').keydown(function (e) {
        prevent_backspace_default(e); //i compare keycode here 
});
```

This is still not perfect as this makes no list pop up where i do want the list to pop up but I want the list to contain all the list options not just the ones that match the previous input.

How do you prevent the default input options pop up event and how can you trigger it after you perform some actions?

I have tried disabling the default event oninput and onchange but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Not so sure though, may be you are looking for the autocomplete option here.https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp

Comment: I have tried the autocomplete option before and it doesnt work. Thanks for the tip though

Comment: I ended up clearing the input on mousedown and it works. I think the options trigger on mouse down. Still dont know how to trigger the dropdown event so im leaving the question open but its possible there is no way to trigger it